# .htaccess "Allow from" and additional statement

Tags: apache-2.4, permissions, .htaccess

I need to create some .htaccess configuration and I need some help with it. My apache version is 2.4. Running on Ubuntu.

The task:

1) allow access to test-uri-1 for authenticated users and for users with "white" IP address;

2) allow access to test-uri-2 and test-uri-3 only for authenticated users;

3) allow access to all another URIs with no restrictions;

4) it should work using only .htaccess file in root of web project.

My first code example:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^test-uri-1$ require_auth=true
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^test-uri-2$ require_auth=true
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^test-uri-3$ require_auth=true
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^test-uri-2$ require_auth_force=true
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^test-uri-3$ require_auth_force=true
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Secure area"
AuthUserFile /wwwroot/.htpasswd
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
<If "-z reqenv('require_auth_force')">
    Allow from 1.2.3.4  4.3.2.1  1.1.1.1  2.2.2.2   
</If>
Satisfy any
Require valid-user
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

This solution doesn't work. As it turned out, IF condition could check EnvVar only if it was defined in server configuration (but I am able use only the .htaccess file). In this example password for test-uri-1 is always required. Even if the user has "white" IP address.

My second code example:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^test-uri-1$ require_auth=true
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^test-uri-2$ require_auth=true
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^test-uri-3$ require_auth=true
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Secure area"
AuthUserFile /wwwroot/.htpasswd
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
<If "'%{REQUEST_URI}' = 'test-uri-1'">
    Allow from 1.2.3.4  4.3.2.1  1.1.1.1  2.2.2.2   
</If>
Satisfy any
Require valid-user
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

This solution doesn't work too. And I know why it is so. The password is required for test-uri-1 even the user has "white" IP address too.

Could you help me? Many thanks!